# Android GridView нажатие на 2 элемента

Tags: android

Как создать GridView типа как тетрадная клетка с возможностью выделять только 2 элемента и строго или по вертикали, или по горизонтали?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

1. Заведите массив `int[] coord = new int[2];` и флаг `boolean couldPress = true`
2. При первом нажатии (если `couldPress == true`) запишите в `coord` номер колонки и порядковый номер в строке нажатого элемента.
3. При каждом следующем нажатии проверяйте, что координаты нажатого элемента отличаются не больше чем на один от одного из элементов массива и не отличаются от другого.
4. Если условие из п.2 выполняется, то в переменную `couldPress` запишите `false`.

Comment: А как взять порядковый номер в строке?

Comment: @Digetix, если число столбцов вы задаёте статическим (3, например) и вам известно кол-во отображаемых элементов, то вычислить это будет не сложно.